# Where do OS X software updates download to?

Tags: macos

I got disconnected from the Internet halfway through a software update on my OS X system, and it didn't delete the incomplete download. I now don't have enough disk space to do the update.

Are there any other OS X-specific temp files I can delete?

Comment: Is there anything in Library->Updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `Library->Updates`. There may be some caches hidden elsewhere, but I think Updates is the main folder.

(Note: at first this was a comment, but since I think it helped, I'm turning it into an answer).

Comment: Not sure this is true anymore on Lion. At least, I just downloaded 10.7.2 and that folder only has a `plist` in it.